# "Undefined variable: users" when trying to use @foreach

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to make foreach loop in laravel to list all users but when I use the code that laravel suggested I get this error:

```
Undefined variable: users (View: /home/vagrant/Code/SimFly/resources/views/profile.blade.php)
```

The code causing the error is:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
<p>This is user {{ $user->id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Please can someone help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Can you show us your function?

Comment: That error message is crystal clear. `$users` is not defined in that scope. How do you think _we_ can help with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `users` variable in a view you need to pass it from a controller first:

```
$users = User::all();
return view('profile', compact('users'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it worked , I am new to Laravel and was not very sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Its also a great practice to check state (isset, count for example) of the array/variable before looping through it, to protect any unforeseen errors.

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestions above, the problem is that the view was not being passed the variable.

To catch this in the blade template use something like a `@forelse` instead of a `@foreach`

### ProfileController

```
$users = User::all();
return view('profile', [
    'users' => $users
]);
```

### Profile Blade

```
@forelse
    <p>This is user {{ $user->id }}</p>
@empty
    <p>There are no users</p>
@endforelse
```